# Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on take a JSON object and persist it in a relational database: 
entity:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

...

private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime ;
public ZonedDateTime getZonedDateTime () {
        return zonedDateTime ;
    }
public void setZonedDateTime (ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime ) {
        this.zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime ;
    }
```

I have add dependency on pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but when I call the Service:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-7) Unexpected error occurred in
 scheduled task.: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.createContextual(InstantDeserializer.java:231)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:685)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:948)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:446)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:296)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializerCache.java:191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationContext.java:422)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:2664)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:162)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:765)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:650)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
```

Here the same problem http://qaru.site/questions/13631592/nosuchfielderror-adjustdatestocontexttimezone-when-trying-to-parse-json

Comment: please provide more information about your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update version "jackson-datatype-jsr310" >=2.8

> Alexey Bychkov (joxerTMD@github)
>   * Contributed #80: Add Support for
>   `JsonFormat.Feature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE`    (2.8.0)
>   /**
>        * Flag for `JsonFormat.Feature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE`
>        *
>        * @since 2.8
>        *

To solve it:
 in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.11</version>
</dependency>
```